# Why is my tableHeaderView disappearing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit

I'm having a strange issue with a table header disappearing after dismissing the keyboard. Here's the how the problem occurs:

1. Select the textfield that is a
   subview of the table header view.
   Keyboard shows up as expected.
2. Scroll the table so that the header
   view is off-screen.
3. Press the return key, which
   dismisses the keyboard, and tell the
   tableview to scroll back to the top.

That all works except there is a big blank area where the header used to be. I can call the header and everything is where it should be in the console. It's only missing visually. Completely baffled, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just heard from someone at Apple. This is a known issue that will be fixed in iOS 4.1. Thanks for the replies everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Had something similar when I was not creating table cells properly. The view would not generate them correctly but allocate the space anyway and not give errors.

It could be that it's being freed up and therefore "disappearing".